# Invalid 'asm': operand is not a condition code, invalid operand code 'c'

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, inline-assembly

I am attempting to build Voxlap on linux from here https://github.com/Ericson2314/Voxlap and when I'm trying to do so I get an error message regarding the inline assembly:

```
source/sdlmain.cpp: In function ‘void fpuinit(long int)’:
source/sdlmain.cpp:1814:3: error: invalid 'asm': operand is not a condition code, invalid operand code 'c'
);
^

source/sdlmain.cpp:1814:3: error: invalid 'asm': operand is not a condition code, invalid operand code 'c'
source/sdlmain.cpp:1814:3: error: invalid 'asm': operand is not a condition code, invalid operand code 'c'
source/sdlmain.cpp:1814:3: error: invalid 'asm': operand is not a condition code, invalid operand code 'c'
```

The offending code is here:

```
static long fpuasm[2];
static inline void fpuinit (long a)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
        "fninit\n"
        "fstcww %c[fp]\n"
        "andb   $240, %c[fp]+1(,1)\n"
        "orb    %%al, %c[fp]+1(,1)\n"
        "fldcww %c[fp]\n"
        :
        : "a" (a), [fp] "p" (fpuasm)
        : "cc"
    );
}
```

The compiler error is pointing to this part

```
 : "cc"
```

Any help deciphering the error message or the actual issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: I did, was there an issue with what I asked?

Comment: Well, provide a [MCVE] as required please.

Comment: My question is regarding building a library and asking for help deciphering the error message or explanations about the specifics of this assembly and why it is outputting this error. There's nothing else I can do beyond provide the code and the error and the context of what I'm building.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're using the `c` operand code incorrectly. The `c` operand code is the letter `c` in `%c[fp]`.  It's saying the operand `[fp] "p" (fpuasm)` isn't a condition code, which it doesn't appear to be. As for the actual issue it's hard to say what it might it be given that you haven't provided a MCVE, but I'd guess that you're trying to compile this code for a non-x86 target.

Comment: What processor are you using (compiling for)?

Comment: @RossRidge : The `%c` operand modifier allows one to place a constant value without decorations (punctuation)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm compiling on a 64 bit machine, but I'm using -m32 flag because the library is 32 bit only atm

Comment: 64-bit x86 or arm? What *C* / *C++* compiler?

Comment: Full command: g++ -o binaries/sdlmain1.elf.o -funsigned-char -m32 -mfpmath=sse -msse -m3dnow -ffast-math -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-but-set-variable `sdl-config --cflags` -D USEV5ASM=1 -I ./include -c source/sdlmain.cpp -D USEKZ -D ZOOM_TEST     @MichaelPetch x86, g++

Comment: I'm going to guess you are on some Ubuntu based distro >= 16.10 and building a position independent executable by default. Try adding the _G++_ compiler option `-fno-pie` . The code in question doesn't take into account that the `"p"` constraint doesn't work as expected with the default `-fpie` (this default changed on Ubuntu >= 16.10).

Comment: @MichaelPetch The 'c' operand modifier/code seems to have two purposes. It appears it's using the undocumented purpose its complaining about because the operand can't be emitted as a constant, which appears to be true. My guess is that code relies on optimization being turned on. It also appears that this code probably isn't going to end up do anything useful since the flag `-mfpmath-sse` is being used.

Comment: @RossRidge : It seems with `-fpie` which is the default for newer Ubuntu distros that the `"p"` operand is confusing _G++_. `%c` operand modifier can't take a register name and GCC produces the unusual error seen here when applied to `%c[fp]`. In my tests generating non-PIE (`-fno-pie`) executables resolves this issue.

Comment: The instruction generated for `%[fp]` looks like `fstcww _ZL6fpuasm@GOTOFF(%ecx)` Of course that is position independent but that can't be converted to a constant. I think the error message for this circumstance doesn't really say what is really going on.

Comment: @MichaelPetch How are you defining `fpuasm`?

Comment: @RossRidge The same way the code (`sdlmain.cpp`) linked to in the question does: `static long fpuasm[2];`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Weird, I never would've guessed that.

Comment: @RossRidge : up until last week I wouldn't have guessed it either. But there has been an uptick in Ubuntu >= 16.10 (or ones based upon it) and I have found myself  considering _PIE_ being enabled as being the cause of issues. Lucked out in this case ;-)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant that `fpuasm` was a 2 element array of longs. But I wouldn't guessed PIE being the problem either, despite the fact that I've seen you diagnose it as the problem before.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm on Debian Stretch not Ubuntu but you're correct about the position independent thing , using gcc6. Code posted by Ross fixed the issue, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael Petch explains the immediate cause of the problem is probably because Ubuntu now ships with a version of GCC that creates position independent executables (PIE) by default. The asm statement doesn't work when the compiler is producing position independent code (PIC). You can probably replace the code with the following, as it should be equivalent:

```
// set up the x87 FPU, ignoring the SSE MXCSR used for normal FP operations in x86-64 or 32-bit with -mfpmath=sse
static inline void fpuinit (long a)
{
    asm volatile (
        "mov %1, %0\n\t"
        "fninit\n\t"
        "fldcw %0\n"
        : "=m" (*(short *)fpuasm)    // *OUTPUT* operand, not input
        : "ir" ((short) (0x037F & 0xF0FF | (a & 0xFF) << 8)));
}
```

Or better, assign to `fpuasm` outside the asm (with `memcpy` if you want to only set the first 2 bytes), or not at all and just use a local `tmp`.  (Source + compiler-generated asm for both ways [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'static+long+fpuasm%5B2%5D%3B%0A%0A//static+inline+%0Avoid+fpuinit_asm_mov+(long+a)%0A%7B%0A++++asm+volatile+(%0A++++++++%22mov+%251,+%250%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++%22fninit%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++%22fldcw+%250%5Cn%22%0A++++++++:+%22%3Dm%22+(*(short+*)fpuasm)%0A++++++++:+%22ir%22+((short)+(0x037F+%26+0xF0FF+%7C+(a+%26+0xFF)+%3C%3C+8)))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A//static+inline+%0Avoid+fpuinit+(long+a)%0A%7B%0A++++short+tmp+%3D+(0x037F+%26+0xF0FF)+%7C+((a+%26+0xFF)+%3C%3C+8)%3B%0A++++memcpy(fpuasm,+%26tmp,+sizeof(tmp))%3B++//+strict-aliasing+safe%0A++++asm+volatile+(%0A++++++++%22fninit%5Cn%5Ct%22%0A++++++++%22fldcw+%250%5Cn%22%0A++++++++::+%22m%22+(*(short+*)fpuasm)++//+not+strict-aliasing+safe%0A++++++++//%22m%22+(tmp)++//+could+just+use+a+local%0A++++++++)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A/*+updates+SSE+MXCSR,+too,+and+no+clear+way+to+apply++%60a%60%0A%23include+%3Cfenv.h%3E%0Avoid+ISO_setenv(long+a)+%7B%0A++++fesetenv(FE_DFL_ENV)%3B%0A%7D%0A*/'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:35.56064390785457,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell+-fPIE',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:32.198852985294394,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:32.198852985294394,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell++-fPIE',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.240503106851044,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  This still has warnings about strict aliasing, but at least we tell the compiler this function writes `fpuasm`, not reads it.

---

This replaces the awkward `"p"` "pointer" constraint and the `c` "constant" operand modifier that it needs to make it work with a simple `"m"` "memory" constraint. This has the advantage working regardless of whether it's being compiled as PIC or not. It also works on both 32-bit and 64-bit targets.

I also took the liberty of optimizing the code by taking advantage of the fact that the FNINIT instruction sets the FPU control word to a known state (0x037F) so there's no need to use the FSTCW instruction to read it.

It was also silly to use two memory-destination AND/OR instructions, instead of preparing the value in a register.